# Golang. Получить температуры видеокарты, процессора и HDD в windows

Tags: golang, процессор, gpu

Можно ли получить температуру цпу, видеокарты и дисков используя golang в винде? Если да, то подскажите что использовать для этого. Заранее спасибо

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/golang/comments/gppdls/query_cpu_and_gpu_temperature_in_windows/